# iOS how to know if the html5 button was clicked loaded on an UIWebView

Tags: ios, html, webview

I have an iOS app with an UIWebView, and I need to receive a href url from server side and then present the web page which is a HTML5 from that href in my UIWebView:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
myVC.url = serverSideResponse.href;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In the MyViewController.m, I have this:

```
_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
[self.view addSubView:_webView];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

So the web page is from server side and I want my iOS app/webview to know if the button was clicked on that page. To be more specific, if that button was clicked, then I shut my webview (meaning removeFromSuperView).

Now what I can see is that when I check the source code of that web page, I know the button id.

The url I received was: `https://api.uber.com/v1/surge-confirmations/edbfdd9a-276b-4b85-b3f4-5a0c948a17fe`. And when I was loading it in my web view, it has a button and when I clicked it nothing happened, only console logged the click event and the request was: `https://api.uber.com/v1/surge-confirmations/edbfdd9a-276b-4b85-b3f4-5a0c948a17fe#` <--there comes an extra `#`.

But when I put the url in my desktop browser to present it and click the button, it can redirect to the next url (`https://www.uber.com`) as expected.

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? Have you looked at the web view delegate methods?

Comment: @Wain, I have been looking for a solution for two days but I'm new to it so I didn't find any proper ways. Of course I have looked at the delegate methods. For instance, `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`, this one I tested already, I only added `return YES;` but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you log the parameters it was passed to see what they were?

Comment: What happens when you press the button? does the site's URL change? If so you should be able (as you said) to get it with `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` and check the url in the request object.

Comment: @Wain, thanks for your tips. Yes, I found that when I clicked the button, app logged `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`. But I don't know what to say, I tried this yesterday it didn't log anything, I think maybe it's the HTML5 page issue.

Comment: @palme, yes, according to the API document, when I clicked the button, the url should change, the page should've jumped to the redirect url I set earlier, but it didn't respond to the click event and the url remained the same, I think there may be some issues at the server side.

Comment: can you give us a link to the page? does the delegate get called? did you connect you webview.delegate to the controller?

Comment: @palme, yes, I've got all of it ready, I mean I can detect the button click event in the webview delegate callback method, but the page didn't jump to other page. I can see the url is like: before clicking: `https://host/path/token`, after clicking: `https://host/path/token#` which only got an extra `#`, so that's why I suspect that could be a server side issue.

Comment: sounds like they prevent the click with javascript and do some fancy ajax stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Wain and @palme, I found one of the UIWebView delegate callback methods

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

can do this.

Parameter `request` and `navigationType` can tell you what navigationType triggered what request.